# Cannot find symbol error when calling methods in an extended JButton class

Tags: java, methods, jframe, jbutton, subclassing

I need some help resolving this issue. I can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't be working. 
I want to add more methods to my ButtonDefault class which is a subclass of JButton but I keep getting "symbol not found" error.

The code below, instantiation of the ButtonDefault worked, the default color and action of the 
button returned and work just fine. However all of that code is in the constructor of ButtonDefault. 
I want to add additional methods to the ButtonDefault class so later on I can change the color of the 
button and such.

the error that I keep getting:
    MineSweeper.java:50: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method setUpButton()
    location: class javax.swing.JButton
                                        button[i][j].setUpButton();

I have 2 classes.

```
//MineSweeper.java
public class MineSweeper extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener,ItemListener {
    static JButton[][] button = new ButtonDefault[17][31];

    public void tileSetup()
    {
       button[i][j] = new ButtonDefault(i,j, this); //This work just fine
       //These work too - I just don't want it here. 
       //button[i][j].setIcon(null);
       //button[i][j].setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Button.border"));
       //button[i][j].setBackground(null);
       //button[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
       //button[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
       //button[i][j].setEnabled(true);
       button[i][j].setUpButton(); //This don't work. 
    }
}

//ButtonDefault.java
public class ButtonDefault extends JButton implements ActionListener,MouseListener,ItemListener
{
    public ButtonDefault(){};
    public ButtonDefault(int x, int y, final MineSweeper mineObject)
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(18,18));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {  
           //All the code in here work just fine. 
    }

    public void setUpButton()
    {
        this.setIcon(null);
        this.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Button.border"));
        this.setBackground(null);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
        this.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUpButton` is a custom method of `ButtonDefault` not `JButton`. Therefore the array declaration should be

```
private ButtonDefault[][] buttons = new ButtonDefault[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

Notes:

- Generally using `static` declarations indicates poor design so use an instance field instead
- Magic numbers are also perceived as poor design, consider at least using constants

Comment: You can also write `ButtonDefault def = new ButtonDefault(i,j, this); button[i][j] = def; def.setUpButton();`

Comment: Wow...That is so obvious I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!!! Worked great now...

Answer (score 0):

Try casting before calling setUpButton

```
((ButtonDefault)button[i][j]).setUpButton();
```